# Rocket League Multi monitor 3 player screen goes black

Tags: technical-issues, pc, windows, windows-10, rocket-league

I used [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/3dzt68/play_rocket_league_splitscreen_on_multiple/?st=ivf2u91f&sh=e79b79c4) solution to play rocket league split screen using both my monitors. Now I wanted to play with two friends so I added a third controller. This works fine until the game starts. Then you can still hear sound. From the sound I can hear that the controller input also works. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKWdX.jpg) are some pictures that might help visualisering what I mean.

I also tried starting a Exhibition match and adding the extra players after starting the match. This has the same result when the third player is added.

Comment: Is there any additional 3rd party software being used? Have you looked at your event viewer in your Windows OS? If so, are there any errors or warnings?

Comment: I would like to thank you for commenting on this question. This made me start up the game again and try my tree player setup. I found out that the problem no longer exists. My guess is that it was fixed in an graphics driver, rocketleague and/or windows update.

Comment: Would you be able to create an answer with the steps taken and such? Would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question on request of @HazyKingdom. Please let it be known that the answer was found by reddit/youtube user [vi9ke](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/3dzt68/play_rocket_league_splitscreen_on_multiple/?st=ivf2u91f&sh=e79b79c4).

1. Go to you Display settings.
2. Multiply the width of your smallest screen.
3. Remember or write down the the value from step 2 and the height of your smallest screen.
4. Open File Explorer.
5. Go to your documents folder (Probably `C:\Users\{User}\Documents` unless you have changed this yourself).
6. Go further until you are at `C:\Users\{User}\Documents\My Games\Rocket League\TAGame\Config`.
7. Here you want to create a copy of `TASystemSettings.ini` so when you make a mistake you can revert your changes.
8. Open `TASystemSettings.ini` in your preferred text editor.
9. On line 62 there is a value called 'ResX' change the value to the value you found in step 2.
10. On line 63 there is a value called 'ResY' change the value to the height of your smallest screen (step 3).
11. Start up RocketLeague
12. Go to Options > Video and set 'Windowmode' to windowed or borderless (whatever works best for you).
13. Go to Options > Misc and make sure 'Horizontal Splitscreen' is unchecked.
14. If during the game you see objects not being rendered or a black screen. Go to Options > Video and set 'Render Quality' to 'High Quality'.

This answer is tested on Windows 10.